# Linux - how to get count of line in file

Tags: command-line, command-substitution, wc

Can you tell me how to get the line count in a script?

```
PID_COUNT = 'cat /david/file1/test.sh | wc -l '
```

is not working, shows an error "illegal -l".

Comment: Piping to `wc -l` works here. Which Linux distro or UNIX system is this? Do you use `wc` from `coreutils`? Do you use a dash (`-`) and the letter l (`l`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of lines in `/david/file1/test.sh` use

```
wc -l </david/file1/test.sh
```

If you want to count the number of lines that `/david/file1/test.sh` produces when run:

```
/david/file1/test.sh | wc -l
```

If you want to store that in a variable:

```
line_count=$( wc -l </david/file1/test.sh )
```

or

```
line_count=$( /david/file1/test.sh | wc -l )
```

depending on whether you want to count the number of lines in the file or the number of lines in the output of the script.

There are two things wrong with your command `PID_COUNT = 'cat /david/file1/test.sh | wc -l'`

1. Assignments are required to have no space around `=`.
2. The variable `PID_COUNT` will be a string, not to output of the command. This is due to the single quotes.  To capture the output of a command, use `$( ... )` as above.

In either case, the error is most likely "PID_COUNT: command not found" rather than "illegal -l".